# How to make sql query use index range scan

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a question about how mysql optimizes queries.

```
select *
from pp
where 1
    and timestamp >= '2016-01-01' and timestamp <= '2017-01-03'
    and (s = 0 or s is NULL)
    and (
        from in (select col from Temp)
        or
        to in (select col from Temp2)
    )
order by idx desc limit 0, 100;
```

Mysql uses Full Index Scan on timestamp with two subqueries attached.

I don't understand why it doesn't use index range scan on timestamp first then apply subqueries later.

Is there a particular reason for this?
If not, can I force it to use index range scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM pp AS p
    LEFT JOIN Temp  AS t  ON (p.from = t.col)   -- leading up to `OR`
    LEFT JOIN Temp2 AS t2 ON (p.to   = t2.col)
    WHERE p.timestamp >= '2016-01-01'
      AND p.timestamp  < '2017-01-03'  -- avoids extra midnight
      AND (p.s = 0 OR p.s IS NULL)     -- see note
      AND (t.col IS NOT NULL OR t2.col IS NOT NULL)  -- roundabout `OR`
    ORDER BY p.idx DESC
    LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Note:
Pick `0` or `NULL` for `s`; don't allow both.  That way, one of these indexes can be used for extra efficiency (after you simplify the `AND (..OR..)`:

```
INDEX(s, timestamp)
INDEX(s, idx)
```

If you keep the two values for `s`, then have

```
INDEX(timestamp),
INDEX(idx)
```

although they may or may not be useful/used.

`Temp` and `Temp2` need

```
INDEX(col)  -- unless `col` is already the `PRIMARY KEY`
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE pp` if you need to discuss this further.  It may be handy to see the engine, datatypes, current indexes, etc.

`IN( SELECT ... )` performs poorly.
`OR` optimizes poorly.  (I have tried to mitigate this.)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** I gave the following answer because I had misread the OP’s query. He was asking

```
`from` in (select col from Temp)
or
`to` in (select col from Temp2)
```

while I answered as if he were asking

```
`from` in (select col from Temp)
and
`to` in (select col from Temp2)
```

So, the code below with the two joins effectively represents an `AND` condition. I keep it as it stands, however, as an example of how `JOIN` can be used to represent `AND`, while the code corrected by Rick James in his answer shows how to represent `OR`.

---

If `col` is unique in both `Temp` and `Temp2`, your query should look like

```
  SELECT p.*
    FROM pp p
    JOIN Temp t
      ON (p.from = t.col) 
    JOIN Temp2 t2
      ON (p.to = t2.col)
   WHERE p.timestamp >= '2016-01-01'
     AND p.timestamp <= '2017-01-03'
     AND (p.s = 0 OR p.s IS NULL)
ORDER BY p.idx DESC LIMIT 0, 100;
```

(if `col` is not unique, replace `JOIN Temp t` with `JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col FROM Temp) t` and similarly with `Temp2`).

Granted, this performs the checks on `from` and `to` before the index scan as well, but at least it doesn’t perform two subqueries for each row...

Comment: I don't think this formulation is correct -- the OP has `OR` between the two lookups; you are effectively saying `AND`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I had misread the OP’s query. I edited my answer.