# Distinct keyword is very slow when used in where clause. Any replacement for this that can speed up the query?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Suppose there are 2 tables - s1 and r1.

I have to return all rows of s1 only where s1.Salary is present in r1.Salary. Here Salary is a column name.

Now the below query works fine but it is extremely slow for very big datasets.

```
SELECT * FROM s1 where s1.Salary in  (select distinct r1.Salary from r1)
```

Is there any way to speed up this query or a different query to perform the same thing?

Comment: What happens if you simply do just SELECT? (Should be the same query result.)

Comment: This seems like you are simply trying to get all the distinct from the Salary table, could you just do `select distinct * from s1.salary`

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn HI, I have updated my query.

Comment: @jarlh, Even if we remove distinct keyword it will still not speed up enough.

Comment: Show us table and index definitions. And the explain output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` on an index, instead of materializing data using `DISTINCT`.

Create the index:

```
create index ix1 on r1 (salary);
```

Then, the query can take the form:

```
select *
from s1
where exists (select 1 from r1 where r1.salary = s1.salary)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a Join. Should perform better:

```
SELECT s1.* 
FROM s1 
INNER JOIN (select distinct Salary from s1) q ON s1.Salary = q.Salary
```

Comment: Your query works. But does this really work better in terms of speed?

Comment: Wheres clauses with IN usually perform worst than inside the Join. I don't know the reason.  Here you can see another post that recommend the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41452463/19232033

Comment: The reason is that MySQL sometimes runs the subquery once for each row of the outer query, if it can't figure out that it should be run only once and the result reused. If you use the `FROM (...subquery...)` form like this answer, it will certainly run the subquery just once and preserve the result in a temporary table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to limit the data to only the r1 distinct data then join it back to the CTE I suppose

```
WITH R_CTE
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT SALARY FROM R1
)
SELECT * FROM S1 S JOIN R_CTE R ON R.SALARY = S.SALARY
```